Swagger Not Generating Routes/ Docs in Flask with flask_openapi3
I am new to Flask and still learning how to properly set up and configure it, and i m struggle with documentation.
I'm working on a Flask application that uses blueprints to organize my routes, and I’m documenting the API with flask_openapi3. However, when I access Swagger via http://127.0.0.1:5000/openapi/swagger, I only see the title of my API and no routes are documented.
/my_project
    /app
        __init__.py
        /main
            routes.py
        /hello
            routes.py
    run.py

run.py
from app import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

app/init.py
from .main.routes import main_bp
from .hello.routes import hello_bp
from flask_openapi3 import OpenAPI, Info

def create_app():
    app = OpenAPI(__name__, info=Info(title="API PROJECT Data", version="1.0.0"))
    app.register_blueprint(main_bp, url_prefix='/main')
    app.register_blueprint(hello_bp, url_prefix='/hello')
    return app

example app/hello/routes.py:
from flask import Blueprint

hello_bp = Blueprint('hello', __name__)

@hello_bp.get('/hello')
def hello():
    """
    Hello Route
    ---
    description: Returns a hello message.
    responses:
      200:
        description: Successful response
    """
    return 'Hello'

routes map :
Map([<Rule '/static/<filename>' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> static>,
 <Rule '/openapi/static/<filename>' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> openapi.static>,
 <Rule '/openapi/openapi.json' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> openapi.api_doc>,
 <Rule '/openapi/swagger' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> openapi.swagger>,
 <Rule '/openapi/redoc' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> openapi.redoc>,
 <Rule '/openapi/rapidoc' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> openapi.rapidoc>,
 <Rule '/openapi/' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> openapi.openapi>,
 <Rule '/main/data' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> main.get_data>,
 <Rule '/main/modality' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> main.get_columns>,
 <Rule '/main/filter' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> main.filter_data>,
 <Rule '/hello/hello' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> hello.index>,
 <Rule '/hello/hello2' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> hello.index2>])

All routes works well , the problem is only that i have no docs. no information with http://127.0.0.1:5000/openapi/ !
I saw that in http://127.0.0.1:5000/openapi/openapi.json
in paths , I have nothing ....
Thanks for your help !
